# Wheel numbers visible outside wheel

Tags: mobiscroll

With v:2.4, FF18, using datetime demo, if I click-drag the number wheel up/down, the numbers go momentarily outside the wheel area, then disappear and then wheel is actually scrolled. This did not happen in v:2.0. Is there a way to avoid this effect, or is it a bug?

Sorry, hard to get a screen shot; it just happens for an instant, but looks ugly.

---

Got a screenshot
[image]

Comment: With [time](http://demo.mobiscroll.com/datetime/time#theme=default) demo, this behavior happens with hour/ampm wheel, but not with the minutes...

Comment: Seem to be a weird FF 18 issue... not sure what it is yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's fixed in 2.4.1
The issue did not happen in 2.0 (and 2.1) because the `top` property was animated instead of the hardware accelerated `translate3d`, which provides more fluid animations, but appears to behave funky on FF18.

Surprisingly removing the `border-radius` from the `.dww` class (the animation container) looks like solved the issue.