# Wheel numbers in FF18

Tags: mobiscroll

Re: [wheel #s outside wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678963/wheel-numbers-visible-outside-wheel) (@dioslaska)

That issue is fixed, but now numbers make funny shadow inside wheel (also in demo page)...

[image: demo page]

or is there another animation parameter to disable this?

Comment: Does not happen on my machine... maybe it's hardware dependent?

Comment: Don't think so; as with the other case, it does not happen with the minutes, just the hours.